# ¿Cómo hago casting de manera correcta? (Java)

Tags: java, poo, herencia, polimorfismo, casting

Tengo este algoritmo de acá

```
    //Java
    class Vehiculo{
        public void imprimirSonido(){System.out.println("A");}
    }

    class Coche extends Vehiculo{
        public void imprimirSonido(){System.out.println("B");}
    }

    class Bicicleta extends Vehiculo{
        public void imprimirSonido(){System.out.println("C");}
    }

    public class Test{
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Vehiculo v=new Coche();
            Bicicleta b=(Bicicleta)v;
            v.imprimirSonido();
            b.imprimirSonido();
        }
    }
```

Y me genera error por querer convertir "v" (de tipo Coche) a tipo Bicicleta. Pensé en  darle valor a "b" como un tipo "Vehiculo" y luego pasarlo a tipo "Bicicleta", pero eso iría en contra de la herencia y sale error. Por eso quería saber si hay alguna manera de hacerle casting.

Aparte quería saber cuál es la parte que, a la hora de instar un objeto, es la que define qué tipo de objeto será. Por ejemplo, en el algoritmo que presento en "v", ¿es de tipo Coche o de tipo Vehiculo?

Gracias

Comment: No se entiende cual es el error. El casting que estás haciendo si compila correctamente y se lo denomina [downcasting](https://www.codejava.net/java-core/the-java-language/what-is-upcasting-and-downcasting-in-java).

Comment: @MrDave1999 ese código si bien compila no funciona, puesto que vas a tener un `java.lang.ClassCastException` en tiempo de ejecución ya que `v` no es una `Bicicleta`.

Comment: @E.Betanzos No me había fijado en ese detalle. Jeje que despistado. Ahí si dará la excepción. El puntero `b` si o si debe apuntar a un objeto de tipo `Bicicleta`, sin embargo, se le está asignando al puntero una referencia de un objeto de tipo `Coche`, lo cual es erróneo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo primero que debes entender es que cuando trabajamos con herencia y polimorfismo el tipo de la variable no define el tipo de objeto al que hace referencia.

En tu ejemplo, aunque `v` sea una variable de tipo `Vehiculo` el objeto al que hace referencia sigue siendo de tipo `Coche`. Por tal motivo cuando haces un casting lo hace sobre el tipo del objeto referenciado no sobre el tipo definido en la variable. En otras palabras, `v` referencia a un objeto de tipo `Coche` el cual no puede ser casteado a `Bicicleta` ya que un `Coche` no es una `Bicicleta`.

```
Vehiculo v = new Coche();
Coche c = (Coche) v;// Esto es válido ya que v es un Coche

Vehiculo v = new Coche();
Bicicleta b = (Bicicleta) v;// Esto NO es válido ya que v es un Coche y no una Bicicleta

Vehiculo v = new Vehiculo();
Coche c = (Coche) v;// Esto NO es válido ya que v es un Vehiculo y no un Coche
Bicicleta b = (Bicicleta) v;// Esto NO es válido ya que v es un Vehiculo y no una Bicicleta
```

El tipo de la variable solo nos restringe el acceso a los miembros de esa clase aunque el objeto al que haga referencia la variable tenga otros miembros.

```
class Vehiculo{
    public void imprimirSonido(){System.out.println("A");}

    public String getNombreVehiculo(){...}
}

class Coche extends Vehiculo{
    public void imprimirSonido(){System.out.println("B");}

    public void encenderAC(){...}
}

Vehiculo v = new Coche();
v.getNombreVehiculo();// OK, acceso a miembro de la clase Vehiculo
v.encender();// ERROR, encender NO es miembro de la clase Vehiculo
((Coche) v).encender();// OK, primero se castea la variable al tipo del objeto referenciado y luego se accede a un miembro de la clase de este objeto (Coche)
```